# Cutoff Date with Javascript - Is this the right approach?

Tags: javascript

I currently need to display a message on an order receipt notification that let's the use know that if they placed the order before Mondays at 7:00am, that it will ship on Thursday of the same week, and if they placed the order after Mondays at 7:00am, the delivery will go on Thursday of the following week.

Unfortunately I am not a javascript developer, but here is what I got so far:

```
<p id="shipment_note"></p>
<script>
var today, cutDate, text;
today = new Date();
cutDate = new Date();

cutDate.getDay([1])
cutDate.setHours([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

if (today.getDay() <= cutDate) {
text = "Your order will ship next Thursday" ;

} else {
text = "Your order will ship Thursday of next week.";
}
document.getElementById("shipment_note").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

I'm not sure if this approach is right and wanted to get some feedback if possible.

Comment: There is no question in your description.

Comment: You are not explaining your issue, is it working? What's going wrong?

Comment: I think this should be calculated on the server-side based on the time they placed their order, not the time they view the receipt page.

Comment: Hi @fubar in this case the order receipt gets displayed right after the complete order cta is clicked on.

Comment: @OscarDiaz - and the user can never access, nor refresh that page again?

Comment: Hi @fubar they will receive a copy of it via email.

Comment: @OscarDiaz - and if they don't open the email/view the page until later that day, the next day, etc? The time on which you're calculating this will be based on the wrong date/time.

Comment: `cutDate.getDay([1])` does nothing. [*getDay*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getday) doesn't take any parameters, it returns the day number in the week which is not used so just vanishes… ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It says, if it's sunday, or if it's monday before 7....

see [getHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) and [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

```js
const isBeforeMondayAt7 = d=>d.getDay() === 0 ||
  (d=>d.getDay() === 1 && d.getHours() < 7);

if(isBeforeMondayAt7(new Date)){
  alert("Your stuff's comin this thursady");
}else{
  alert("Your stuff's comin next thurzday");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want it to be `d.getDay() === 1 && d.getHours() < 7` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with the code:

```
var today, cutDate, text;
today = new Date();
cutDate = new Date();
```

can be

```
var today = new Date(),
    cutDate = new Date(),
    text;
```

Then:

```
cutDate.getDay([1])
```

does nothing. *getDay* doesn't take any parameters, it returns the day number in the week (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, etc.). The returned value isn't stored or used so this line can be removed.

```
cutDate.setHours([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

[*setHours*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.getday) requires integer parameters, not an array. Passed as values:

```
cutDate.setHours(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

will set the date's time to 0:01:02.003. The rest of the values are ignored.

```
if (today.getDay() <= cutDate) {
```

Here you're comparing the day number to a Date object. The `<=` operator coerces its arguments to number, so *cutDate* will be the time value for the Date, which will always be larger than `today.getDay()` for any date after 1970-01-01T00:00:00.006.

What you want to check is:

1. Is it currently Monday and
2. is the time before 7:00?

If so, set the delivery date to Thursday. If not, set the delivery date for Thursday of the following week. I assume your week starts on Monday not Sunday.

So in that case:

```js
var today = new Date(),
    cutDate = new Date(+today),
    opts = {weekday:'long', day:'numeric', month:'long'},
    text;

// If it's Monday and before 7am
if (today.getDay() == 1 && today.getHours() < 7) { 
  // Set cutDate to Thursday
  cutDate.setDate(cutDate.getDate() + 3);
  text = 'Your order will ship on ' + 
          cutDate.toLocaleString(undefined, opts) ;
} else {
  // Set cutDate to thursday of next week
  cutDate.setDate(cutDate.getDate() + (11 - (cutDate.getDay() || 7)));
  text = 'Your order will ship on ' + 
          cutDate.toLocaleString(undefined, opts) ;
}

console.log('Today is ' + today.toLocaleString(undefined, opts) + '. ' + text);
```

I've included a more useful message (to me anyway). ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! This taught me a lot and works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may have inverted the order of the operators inside the if statement.

Perhaps...

**change this line...**

```
if (today.getDay() <= cutDate) {
```

**to...**

```
if (today.getDay() =< cutDate) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample using a ternary operator:

```
var today = new Date();
var text = new String();

text = (today.getDay() == 0 || (today.getDay() == 1  && today.getHours() < 7) || today.getDay() > 3) ? "Your order will ship next Thursday" : "Your order will ship Thursday of next week";
alert(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this guys?

```
<script>
var today, cutDate, text;
today = new Date();
cutDate = new Date();

cutDate.getDay([1,2,3,4,])
cutDate.setHours([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

if (today.getDay() >= cutDate) {
text = "Your order will ship Thursday of next week." ;

} else if (today.getDay([5,6,7,0])) {
text = "Your order will ship next Thursday";
}
document.getElementById("shipment_note").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```